# SELECT WHERE related record's values have no occurrence

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a `Client` table and a `Devices` table.

A client can have more than one device and a client has an active state as does the device.

I want all the clients that are active but have no active devices.

I INNER JOINED the devices on the clients for all the active clients, thus clients occur more than once, but now I don't know how to select all the clients that have no active device.

This is how my relationships are set up:

**Client**:

```
pkClientID   Name     IsActive
------------------------------
1            Jake     1
2            Philip   1
```

**Device**

```
pkDeviceID  fkClientID  DeviceName  IsActive
---------------------------------------------
1           1           Samsung     1
2           1           Apple       0
3           2           Samsung     0
4           2           Sony        0
```

Since I already have all the active clients how do I select only Philip since he is active but has no active devices?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

using [**`not exists()`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/exists-transact-sql):

```
select *
from client c
where c.isactive = 1 
  and not exists (
    select 1
    from device d
    where d.fkclientid = c.pkclientid
      and d.isactive = 1
      )
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/NCR78612

returns:

```
+------------+--------+----------+
| pkClientid |  Name  | IsActive |
+------------+--------+----------+
|          2 | Philip |        1 |
+------------+--------+----------+
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `not in` or `not exists` or `left join`/`where`:

```
select c.*
from client c
where c.IsActive = 1 and
      not exists (select 1
                  from devices d
                  where d.fkClientID = c.ClientID and d.IsActive = 1
                 );
```